# Symfony2 can't find template file

Tags: symfony, twig

I am having issues using twig templates for email in SF2.

First, I created a template file located at:
`MainBundle/Resources/views/Email/InviteNewUsers.twig`

Next, I rendered the view as the body of my email: `$this->get('mailer')->send($this->renderView('MainBundle:Email:InviteNewUsers.twig', array('code' => $invite->getCode())));`

Unfortunately, this triggers an error: `Unable to find template "MainBundle:Email:InviteNewUsers.twig"`

is there something wrong with my file placement or my render command?

It was suggest that I might need a type in the template name, so I tested with `InviteNewUsers.txt.twig` and received the same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the name of twig template needs to be `InviteNewUsers.{_format}.twig`. so it must be something like `InviteNewUsers.html.twig`, `InviteNewUsers.xml.twig`, or `InviteNewUsers.text.twig` etc

EDIT:

Also if your namespace includes first directory something like `{Company}\BaseBundle\...`, then your template path needs to be `{Company}MainBundle:Email:InviteNewUsers.text.twig`

Comment: I have tested it with `InviteNewUsers.text.twig` and received the same error

Comment: hmm.. Does that template work as a normal html view to display a html page at all? I wonder your bundle name is really MainBundle. I mostly create directory structure something like `.../src/{Company}/BaseBundle/Email` then path to twig template is always `{Company}BaseBundle:Email:*.html.tiwg`

Comment: Hmm, does not work froma normal view, but my bundle is definitely MainBundle: `namespace Kahal\MainBundle\Controller;`

Comment: If you have that namespace, I think your template path should be `KahalMainBundle:Email:InviteNewUsers.text.twig`

Comment: Aha! I Needed company name before bundle name. Thats annyoing.